# How to obtain Latitude and Longitude when clicking on a rectangle in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created rectangle in Google map and would like to obtain Latitude and Longitude in code when a user clicks on the rectangle.

When I click on outside the rectangle I obtain Latitude and Longitude. When I click on the rectangle however, I'm unable to get Latitude and Longitude.

**Here is My code:**

```
var rectangle;
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  function calcBounds(center, size) {
    var n = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.height / 2, 0).lat(),
      s = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.height / 2, 180).lat(),
      e = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.width / 2, 90).lng(),
      w = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.width / 2, 270).lng();
  return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(s, w),
      new google.maps.LatLng(n, e));
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.689055, -89.584747),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });



  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#008000',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    editable: false,
    draggable: false,
    map: map,
    bounds: calcBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.626805, -89.539396),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.626055, -89.538507)).getCenter(), new google.maps.Size(875, 875))
  });



  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#008000',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    editable: false,
    draggable: false,
    map: map,
    bounds: calcBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.750555, -89.633655),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.749805, -89.632766)).getCenter(), new google.maps.Size(875, 875))
  });



  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#008000',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    editable: false,
    draggable: false,
    map: map,
    bounds: calcBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.626805, -89.519833),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.626055, -89.518943)).getCenter(), new google.maps.Size(875, 875))
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alert("Latitude: " + event.latLng.lat() + " " + ", longitude: " + event.latLng.lng());
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/4/)

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a listener to the `rectangle` as you do for the `map` .

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function(event) {
  alert('latitude: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' , longitude: ' + event.latLng.lng()); 
});
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/5/

Comment: Sport Billy ,i used this code by using rectangle instead  map,problem is that i hv 600 rectangles.and u r changed name of rct1,rct2,etc..

Comment: You can not have 3 different variables with the same name and expect one listener to be attached to all of them by using the same name.
When you do that, the listener is attached to the last variable declared with the name `rectangle`. Other option would be to add the listener after declaring each variable like here http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/7/
or even better to avoid re-writing the same listener over and over again make it a function like here http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/8/

Comment: ok,this is also right.i have found 1 another solution.as i'm creating retangles with loop ,so i can give name of each rectangle and click even with loop.

Comment: it works.we have no need to change the name of rectangles.i just put inside loop.with this addListener comes after each var rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a click event to each of your rectangles. For example:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function( event ){
  alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
 });
```

Comment: Then create a function handler, then loop through your array of rectangles and add the handler... See here: http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/9/

Comment: ok,Thanx,check this solution by Sport Billy . i just put code inside loop,with this it comes under each rectangle. check here http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/7/